# Sharepoint: list all Master Pages used in a Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, web

In a SharePoint (MOSS 2007) environment how can I list all the Master Pages (templates) that are used in a site collection?  I need to add some code to the header of every master page, but there are a lot of subsites and I don't want to have to go to each subsite and check what master page it is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing 'stsadm -o enumsubsites -url http://mysite.company.com' then manually checking each subsite, but a better way would be good for future use.